# Nested Rows Larger Than Parent

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with Bootstrap 4 grid layout & I'm working with Vertical forms.

I would like to nest col-lg-9(child) inside col-lg-6(parent).

for Example:

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">First name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Last name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">City</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Street</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Zip</label>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Email address</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Additional info</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Created a sample mock-up for additional explanation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGas2.png)

Comment: Read the [docs on nesting](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting). `col-*` **must** be contained in `row`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are nesting columns directly inside other columns. Don't' do that.

When nesting in a column you must first put a Bootstrap `row` inside it and then put at least one Bootstrap column inside that new row.

Don't ever nest a Bootstrap column directly inside another Bootstrap column.

Here's the nesting structure you must have in your case:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    content goes here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting